# Custom serialization of a POJO using Jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have a pojo like below , When I serialize this Pojo I want the 
Elements of the map to be appear as root elements of the json instead of nested element  under **testMap**

```
public class ProxyConfig implements Serializable {

  private String test;

  private Integer intValue;

  Map<String, String> testMap;
```

Example lets say testMap has two elements in it then the serialized ProxyConfig should look like this:

```
{
  "test" : "testValue",
 "intValue" : 20,
  "testMapkey1" : "value1",
  "testMapkey1" : "value1",
}
```

Not sure How to implement the CustomSerializer to achieve this any inputs would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@JsonAnyGetter` to get the key-values in a `Map` as plain properties when serialize the map in an instance:

```
@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, String> getTestMap() {
    return testMap;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Wilson, that was very easy , I was trying all sort of things to customize serializer etc